# How to use CLASSPATH regarding to mysql drivers? "Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, mysql, database, driver, ubuntu-12.04

I am installing Atlassian Confluence on our Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Server. I downloaded a fully packed installation of Confluence and already installed it on a virtual machine for testing. Now I install it on the server and when it comes to Database configuration I choose MySQL and External DB.
Then I get this error `Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

So I downloaded the specific driver called `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26` and put it in the location it should be in.

```
/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

So far everything is clear, but now I have to configurate my CLASSPATH (and I don't understand what that is for now)

I went for `sudo nano /etc/environment` and that's what the file now looks like :

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64"
CLASSPATH="/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib"
```

Since it is still not working (same error) , I want to know what I else have to do and maybe someone can explain me the process? Any help is upvoted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes when you miss a jar to provide appropriate driver class

try adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

or alternatively you can download jar and put it into your buildpath.

> right click -> buildpath - > configure buildpath - > add external jars

Comment: no rightclick in ubuntu server (just command line) I didn't install any GUI. dependency didn't work out :/

Comment: then you have to add this jar to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep the mysql.jar in your server's lib folder

Comment: you mean I just cp the mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar  into my /lib/ ? there are no other .jar files in it. I can't believe that :P, any more info ? thanks

Comment: I copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar into my /lib-folder and it worked, after I restarted JIRA. The installation process first assumed that it should use the built-in database so I had to start it all over again by deleting the JIRA/dbconfig.xml file. But then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's been months and may be you have fixed this problem,

I would still like to leave my comment:

---

see https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Database+Setup+For+MySQL
notice that "**Stop immediately after the installation, before opening the Confluence Setup Wizard in your browser**" 。
I've got into  a wrong order then, I fixed the problem by restart confluence using

## service confluence restart

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but there is a typo in your /etc/environment file:

```
## You have (missing '=')...
#JAVA_HOME "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64"
## Should be...
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64"
```